# Make a batch file close when a program different from the one it starts closes

Tags: batch, batch-file

I need to make a batch file that starts one program, and closes when another closes, but i cant get the batch file to work without starting two instances of name2. When I only use Start /wait, the batch  opens name2. Thanks!

```
cd (folder)
name.exe (executes name2 with temporary changes)
start "name.exe" /wait name2.exe
```

Comment: So the batch file should start when the computer starts?

Comment: no only when the batch is executed